# EXTJS extract fields values from form.Panel

Tags: extjs4

I created a form with nested container, fieldset and there a few checkbox on the form too.
as far as the form.getValues() can do it extract all values except the checkboxes so I want to extract the fields value manually. However the code sample I found so far

```
var values = {};
form.items.each( function(f) {
  values[f.getName()] = f.getValue();
});
```

not work because the loop can get only the container, fieldset etc but not the actual field (textfield, combo etc). Could someone show me how to proper recursively extract all the field value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because checkboxes dont hava a `getSubmitData()` which `getValues()` uses.

Try `yourForm.getFieldValues()` instead.

Comment: Jerry, using this method I got yourForm.getFieldValues is not a function and I can't find this method in extjs docs

Comment: Oh! found it Ext.form.Basic so here what I did Ext.widget('winform').form.getFieldValues();

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs 4.0 you can use:

```
var fieldValues = Ext.getCmp('yourForm').form.getFieldValues();
```